# Tiny bar above ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'd like to have a blue bar above my `ActionBar` (not using `ActionBarSherlock`) like below:

[image]

I tried to injecting a custom view via `getActionBar().setCustomView(...)` but it only appears in left side of action bar and right side of title and logo. I want the bar to fill the whole width of the app above action bar.

Any idea?

**Update**

The screenshot after applying @Android-Developer solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 9patch image as your `ActionBar`s background or create it with an xml file, which should look something similar to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                   <solid android:color="#5eccff"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="-1dp" android:left="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:top="2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />
                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
        </item>
</selector>
```

Hope this helps you.

**Update by Afshin**

@Android-Developer wrote the following for first item

```
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#33B5E5" /
```

since the `stroke` didn't worked for me, I replaced it with `solid` to fill the whole background with blue color:

```
<solid android:color="#5eccff"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set action bar background drawable containing blue strip at the top?